# Vector of a template classes error: "Template argument 2 is invalid"

Tags: c++, templates, vector, arguments

When I try to add data to the vector, the second argument of the template is invalid for some reason.
Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T, int N>
class Thing {
public: 

    Thing(T type, int n) {
        memVar = type;
        m = n;
    }

    T getMemVar() {
        return memVar;
    }

private:
  T memVar;
  int m;
};

class U {
public:

    U(int i) {
        j = i;
    }

    int getJ () {
        return j;
    }

private:

    int j;
};

int main() {

  U *tester = new U(5);
  int l = 2;

  vector < Thing <U, int N> > v; //I tried using vector < typename Thing <U, int N> > v and my efforts were fruitless.

  v.push_back(Thing <U, int N>(tester, l)); 

  return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
 prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
 prog.cpp:44:31: error: template argument 2 is invalid
        vector < Thing <U, int N> > v;
                           ^
 prog.cpp:44:33: error: template argument 1 is invalid
        vector < Thing <U, int N> > v;

 prog.cpp:44:33: error: template argument 2 is invalid
 prog.cpp:44:36: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
        vector < Thing <U, int N> > v;
                                ^
 prog.cpp:46:9: error: request for member 'push_back' in 'v', which is of non-class type 'int'
        v.push_back(Thing <U, int N>(tester, l)); 
          ^
 prog.cpp:46:34: error: template argument 2 is invalid
        v.push_back(Thing <U, int N>(tester, l)); 
                              ^
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error message. The arguments are of the correct type, but somehow they're still invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template argument marked as `int` *must* be known at compile time, since templates are compile-time construct.

e.g.:

```
Thing<U, 1> aThing;
```

In addition, you don't need to allocate on the heap in the following statement:

```
U *tester = new U(5);
```

You can, just as easily allocate in on a stack:

```
U tester (5);
```

Since, otherwise, you would get compilation error on `push_back`, since `Thing` doesn't have a constructor, that accepts `T*`, and you are trying to create `Thing<T, 1>`.

Also, `memVar` stored in `Thing`, *must* be constructed before entering constructor body, which is impossible, since `memVar` doesn't have default constructor. You can do this by using *constructor initialization list*:

```
Thing(T type, int n) : memVar (type) {
    m = n;
}
```

So, your full code, fixed of the errors mentioned above, would look like:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T, int N>
class Thing {
public: 

    Thing(T type, int n) : memVar (type) {
        m = n;
    }

    T getMemVar() {
        return memVar;
    }

private:
  T memVar;
  int m;
};

class U {
public:

    U(int i) {
        j = i;
    }

    int getJ () {
        return j;
    }

private:

    int j;
};

int main() {

  U tester (5);
  int l = 2;

  vector < Thing <U, 1> > v; //I tried using vector < typename Thing <U, int N> > v and my efforts were fruitless.

  v.push_back(Thing <U, 1>(tester, l)); 

  return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/GeSm4S).

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
    vector < Thing <U, int N> > v;
```

the `int N` should actually be an integer constant, so:

```
    vector < Thing <U, 42> > v;
```

Comment: You were faster, have a +1

Comment: @Agnew Thanks very  much.

Answer (score 0):

`int N` is a declaration. Which makes `Thing <U, int N>` a syntactic nonsense. Just like the first template argument is a concrete type `U`, so the second template argument must be a concrete `int`, such as `42`.

What number you should use depends on what the parameter `N` means: that's something only you know.